# What is the correct collection to use in JAVA for indexing arrays of byte by a string in ordered way?

Tags: java

I am very new to the Java world (c# dev) and I have as asked the requirement to store some arrays of byte that should be indexed by a string and I have to keep the initial order of the collection.
So I was thinking I should use something like :

```
TreeMap<String, byte[]>
```

but is it the right collection to use? I have read that Map does not preserve the order..

Comment: How do you do it in C#?

Comment: "I have to keep the initial order of the collection" What do you mean by this? That the collection should be ordered by earliest inserted first? In any case, you might be interested by this StackOverflow question: [Java Ordered Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663374/java-ordered-map)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), if you want to have the keys in your map ordered by the key values.

> The TreeMap is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys.

Use a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), if you want to have the keys in your map orderd by the time of insertion into the map.

> This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order)